# How can I fetch out specific data from json to output in HTML as pertaining to a button clicked in my markup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

This code outputs all the Name and Height from the JSON file.

Here's the JSON file. Please don't mind the too many code. I just want to make sure I give all the details to the code for more clarity.

```
"next": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2", 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker", 
            "height": "172", 
            "mass": "77", 
            "hair_color": "blond", 
            "skin_color": "fair", 
            "eye_color": "blue", 
            "birth_year": "19BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"
            ], 
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/22/"
            ], 
            "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "C-3PO", 
            "height": "167", 
            "mass": "75", 
            "hair_color": "n/a", 
            "skin_color": "gold", 
            "eye_color": "yellow", 
            "birth_year": "112BBY", 
            "gender": "n/a", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
            ], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:10:51.357000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.309000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/2/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "R2-D2", 
            "height": "96", 
            "mass": "32", 
            "hair_color": "n/a", 
            "skin_color": "white, blue", 
            "eye_color": "red", 
            "birth_year": "33BBY", 
            "gender": "n/a", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/8/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
            ], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:11:50.376000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.311000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/3/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Darth Vader", 
            "height": "202", 
            "mass": "136", 
            "hair_color": "none", 
            "skin_color": "white", 
            "eye_color": "yellow", 
            "birth_year": "41.9BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/13/"
            ], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:18:20.704000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.313000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/4/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Leia Organa", 
            "height": "150", 
            "mass": "49", 
            "hair_color": "brown", 
            "skin_color": "light", 
            "eye_color": "brown", 
            "birth_year": "19BBY", 
            "gender": "female", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/2/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"
            ], 
            "starships": [], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:20:09.791000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.315000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/5/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Owen Lars", 
            "height": "178", 
            "mass": "120", 
            "hair_color": "brown, grey", 
            "skin_color": "light", 
            "eye_color": "blue", 
            "birth_year": "52BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:52:14.024000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.317000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/6/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Beru Whitesun lars", 
            "height": "165", 
            "mass": "75", 
            "hair_color": "brown", 
            "skin_color": "light", 
            "eye_color": "blue", 
            "birth_year": "47BBY", 
            "gender": "female", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:53:41.121000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.319000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/7/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "R5-D4", 
            "height": "97", 
            "mass": "32", 
            "hair_color": "n/a", 
            "skin_color": "white, red", 
            "eye_color": "red", 
            "birth_year": "unknown", 
            "gender": "n/a", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/"
            ], 
            "species": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/species/2/"
            ], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:57:50.959000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.321000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/8/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Biggs Darklighter", 
            "height": "183", 
            "mass": "84", 
            "hair_color": "black", 
            "skin_color": "light", 
            "eye_color": "brown", 
            "birth_year": "24BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [], 
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/"
            ], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T15:59:50.509000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.323000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/9/"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "Obi-Wan Kenobi", 
            "height": "182", 
            "mass": "77", 
            "hair_color": "auburn, white", 
            "skin_color": "fair", 
            "eye_color": "blue-gray", 
            "birth_year": "57BBY", 
            "gender": "male", 
            "homeworld": "https://swapi.dev/api/planets/20/", 
            "films": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/2/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/4/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/5/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ], 
            "species": [], 
            "vehicles": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/38/"
            ], 
            "starships": [
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/48/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/59/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/64/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/65/", 
                "https://swapi.dev/api/starships/74/"
            ], 
            "created": "2014-12-10T16:16:29.192000Z", 
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:50.325000Z", 
            "url": "https://swapi.dev/api/people/10/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a piece of my markUp

```
<article class="product">
          <div class="img-container">
            <img src="img/r5-d4.jpg" alt="luke-skywalker" class="product-img" />
            <button class="bag-btn" id="getInfo">Info</button>
          </div>
        </article>
```

And this is the js. I used the fetch - api module to access the JSON file. I'm trying to output just the name and the height of the Star Wars characters.

```
const characterInfo = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (let i = 0; i < characterInfo.length; i++) {
  const elem = characterInfo[i];
  elem.addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        let output;

        data.results.forEach((char) => {
          output += `
          <div>
            <h3>${char.name}</h3>
            <h4>${char.height}</h4>
        </div>
            `;
          console.log(char.name);
          console.log(char.height);
        });

        characterInfo.innerHTML = output;
      });
  });
}
```

Right now it outputs all the names and height from the JSON file. How do I make it only output the name "Luke Skywalker" and his height?

Comment: Question has conflicting objectives here. In one place you say you want the Star Wars characters and at the end you say you only want one of them. If you only want one how is it to be determined ? The first item returned in the array or by search within the array?

Comment: If you just want `Luke Skywalker`, you can filter `results` array by `name === 'Luke Skywalker'`

Comment: @charlietfl, I'm sorry for not being explicit enough. I meant it I want if a button  linked an image is clicked, it fetches the name and height of the identity of the image. That is the person or object appearing in the image.

Comment: You need something in the markup that matches a value in the data to do that. How is the markup generated?